# Can Hive in Cloudera work without database like(Mysql,Oracle)

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I install Cloudera and want use Hive, but it not work. Can you explain do I need install same database (Oracle or MySQL) for norm work hive, or it is not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Derby database is by default and it can only support one active user at a time. so for learning purpose you don't need MySQL/Oracle. if you need to explore more options read ~~> [Configuring the Hive Metastore](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html)

> Cloudera recommends using this mode for experimental purposes only. 
>   This is the default metastore deployment mode for CDH. In this mode
>   the metastore uses a Derby database, and both the database and the
>   metastore service run embedded in the main HiveServer process. Both
>   are started for you when you start the HiveServer process. This mode
>   requires the least amount of effort to configure, but it can support
>   only one active user at a time and is not certified for production
>   use.

Comment: can your help me in this question,when i create database retail;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe can your help me fix it error

Comment: sure, add more info on `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml` file content. and version of hive: `hive --version`, also did you try to restart hive from cloudera manager? that should solve your problem as cloudera manager auto-generates `hive-site.xml` file.

Comment: can your give me advice if i have Pc with intel processor 5 3 generation and have 4G memory can i install cloudera in virtual mashine and work with it?

Comment: NO - in order to run cloudera VM you need at least 16 gb RAM. so you can assign 10GB to VM. (8 GB also works but you wont be able to start cloudera manager) - here you get system requirements: http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-7.html